# Stop pd.read_html from converting scientific notation lookalike string "0E10" to float 0.0

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing some webscraping and using the built-in pandas read_html function. One of my columns has a bunch of string in the format "0E10", "0E25", "0E8", etc.
Pandas is being *too* smart and recognizing that 0E10 is scientific notation for 0.0.

Is there a way to disable this functionality?

If possible I'd still like it to smart convert other columns to types (I have 2 other columns that are floats and should be floats in the output df).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. If anybody has a prettier solution (a one-liner?), please share.

`read_html` has a converters parameter!

```
df = pd.read_html(url, converters = {'ColName': str})
```

works well.

Hope this is useful to somebody someday who also spent hours trying to figure out why pandas is converting a string to 0.0!

Comment: rather try `dtypes={'ColName': str}`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Are you sure? I can't find `dtypes` in the docs. But `converters = {'ColName': str}` should definitely work. Why writing a wrapper function when it doesn't do anything else than calling `str`?

Comment: My experience is whatever works for `read_csv` works for `read_excel`. Never tried `read_html`. And also `dtype` not `dtypes`.

Comment: Yes, because `dtype` is part of the docs of both `read_csv`and `read_excel`, but not of `read_html`. And btw you wrote `dtypes`, which I only referred to.